# Elasticsearch- how to do query with condition and sort out the required fied without duplicate

Tags: elasticsearch

i was new to ES, i am now able to sort a field in my DB with condition
alarm!=0
the code was here:

```
    {
    "size":1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "term": {
          "header.alarmStatus": 0
        }
      }
    }//bool
   //query
  }
}
```

and it shows that it have around 4000 hit which is all i want
the response for that (size = 1) was as follow

```
"hits": {
    "total": {
        "value": 3842,
        "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 0.0,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "index123",
            "_type": "meter",
            "_id": "63iti3QBSliyJ__JFt6C",
            "_score": 0.0,
            "_source": {
                "header": {
                    "meterId": 1245,
                    
                },
                "data": {
                    "seqNum": 72
                  
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And my question is how can i do the query with condition "header.alarmStatus": !=0
and list all the meter ID with duplicate counts ?
thanks

Jeff

Comment: can you please share your expected search result and please explain what do you mean by **duplicate counts** here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can understand, you need to list all the `meterId` (removing the duplicate count) for the query with the condition `"header.alarmStatus": !=0`. For this, you can use the terms aggregation with cardinality aggregation as sub aggregation

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "header": {
    "meterId": 1246,
    "alarmStatus": 3
  },
  "data": {
    "seqNum": 72
  }
}
{
  "header": {
    "meterId": 1246,
    "alarmStatus": 2
  },
  "data": {
    "seqNum": 72
  }
}
{
  "header": {
    "meterId": 1245,
    "alarmStatus": 1
  },
  "data": {
    "seqNum": 72
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "term": {
          "header.alarmStatus": 0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "genres": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "header.meterId"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "item_count": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "header.meterId"       
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "aggregations": {
    "genres": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 1246,
          "doc_count": 2,
          "item_count": {
            "value": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "key": 1245,
          "doc_count": 1,
          "item_count": {
            "value": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: @Man Man Yu any luck with this?

Comment: @Man Man Yu it's been a long time. Did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: @ManManYu Glad this worked for you :) Thank u for accepting my answer, can you please upvote the answer as well :)